# How do I render partials and jade files with Angular and Express 4.0?

Tags: angularjs, express, pug, partials

I looked online a few places, but most of it was for Express 2-3. I know I need to put information about partials somewhere, but I don't know where or how exactly to map it out. Basically, my page goes from '/' to '/game', where I want to have a SPA, but I'm having issues rendering jade templates inside this page. I copied a test page but I keep causing crashes attempting to get it to load something from either /views or /partials. Since my page becomes angular-heavy not on index, I didn't understand where to put the code about partials. In app.js? in game.js? In index.js? Somewhere else? And what exactly do I put?

in layout.js

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title test title
     script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js')
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js')
    script(src='script.js')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
```

in app.js

```
// catch-all route so non-explicitly defined routes load angular routes
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('home'); //
});
```

home.jade

```
extends layout
block content
  body(ng-app='RoutingApp')
    h2 AngularJS Routing Example
    p
      | Jump to the 
      a(href='#first') first
      |  or 
      a(href='#second') second page
    div(ng-view='')
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('RoutingApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config( ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) 
    {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/first', {
            // templateUrl: 'views/last' // THIS CRASHES THE PAGE
            // templateUrl: 'last' // so does this
            templateUrl: 'last.jade' // this doesn't, but serves up static file instead of rendering jade
        })
        .when('/second', {
            templateUrl: 'second.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Route has registered with `/`, so you need to use `href` as `#/first` & `#/second`

```
p
  | Jump to the 
  a(href='#/first') first
  |  or 
  a(href='#/second') second page
```

Comment: @CustardBoy does it helped?